Disneyland park modeling for netlogo simulation
I have retrieved geographic data about Disneyland Park. The goal of this student project is to simulate tourist traffic in the park. My netlogo code reads a csv file that contains the geographic data of the park. I managed to draw something (see screenshot). But it is not pretty and it looks like it is clearly missing coordinates.
I would like to point out that the geographic data was retrieved from overpass studio.

Here are some lines from my csv file :
geometry,coordinates,name
Polygon,2.7725516/48.8732829/2.7725713/48.8733074/2.7721337/48.8734698/2.7720344/48.8734644/2.7720545/48.8733571/2.7721562/48.8733212/2.7721408/48.8732999/2.7723631/48.8732216/2.7723674/48.8732285/2.772395/48.8732187/2.7723992/48.8732239/2.7724801/48.8731966/2.7725516/48.8732829,
Polygon,2.7758272/48.8748432/2.7758852/48.8748191/2.7759688/48.8747843/2.7761677/48.874781/2.7762432/48.8748093/2.77631/48.8748307/2.7763123/48.8748707/2.7761721/48.8749208/2.775973/48.8749238/2.7758294/48.8748789/2.7758272/48.8748432,
Polygon,2.7737128/48.8743267/2.7737251/48.8743336/2.7737801/48.8743233/2.7738235/48.8743472/2.7738188/48.8743861/2.7738888/48.8744253/2.7739437/48.8744169/2.7739811/48.8744395/2.773975/48.8744736/2.7739852/48.8744793/2.7738872/48.8745522/2.7738486/48.8745723/2.7737961/48.8745836/2.773764/48.874583/2.7736686/48.8745316/2.7735731/48.8744801/2.7735772/48.8744492/2.7736005/48.8744157/2.7737128/48.8743267,
Polygon,2.7725078/48.8702505/2.7725066/48.8702394/2.7724959/48.8702395/2.7724876/48.8702074/2.7724793/48.8701732/2.7724743/48.8701406/2.7724709/48.8701069/2.7724443/48.8701068/2.772445/48.8700679/2.7724458/48.870028/2.7724367/48.870026/2.7724789/48.8699306/2.7724882/48.8699328/2.772556/48.8698637/2.7725689/48.86987/2.7726352/48.8698232/2.7727048/48.8697764/2.7727129/48.8697802/2.7727226/48.8697713/2.7729646/48.8699015/2.7730696/48.8699563/2.7730233/48.8700625/2.7730365/48.8700648/2.773013/48.8701182/2.7730003/48.8701156/2.7729524/48.8702196/2.7728062/48.8702298/2.7727038/48.8702369/2.7725284/48.8702491/2.7725078/48.8702505,
LineString,2.7714244/48.8743077/2.7715001/48.8742675/2.7715495/48.8742031/2.771789/48.8741312/2.7718316/48.8740681/2.7720807/48.8740025,
LineString,2.7721376/48.8738954/2.772141/48.8738882/2.7720608/48.8738456/2.7720738/48.8736448,
LineString,2.7720738/48.8736448/2.772037/48.8736432/2.771935/48.8736388,
LineString,2.7720807/48.8740025/2.772112/48.8739422,
LineString,2.772112/48.8739422/2.7721376/48.8738954,
LineString,2.7764778/48.8718349/2.7765219/48.8718035,
LineString,2.7764129/48.8718785/2.7764778/48.8718349,
LineString,2.7765219/48.8718035/2.7765518/48.8717826,
LineString,2.7746006/48.8712008/2.7746011/48.8712041/2.7744042/48.8712198,

And there is my code :
extensions [csv]

globals [
  coordinates-data
  min-lat max-lat min-lon max-lon  ; Pour ajuster l'échelle de la carte
]





;;;;;;;;;; UTILS ;;;;;;;;;;

to-report split [input separator]
  let items []
  let start 0
  let input-string (word input "")
  let next-separator-position position separator input-string

  while [is-number? next-separator-position and next-separator-position != -1] [
    set items lput (substring input-string start next-separator-position) items
    set start (next-separator-position + length separator)

    let remaining-input substring input-string start (length input-string)
    set next-separator-position position separator remaining-input

    if is-number? next-separator-position and next-separator-position != -1 [
      set next-separator-position start + next-separator-position
    ]
  ]

  set items lput (substring input-string start (length input-string)) items
  report items
end



to-report convert-latlon-to-netlogo [lat lon]
  let y (lon - min-lon) * world-width / (max-lon - min-lon)
  let x (lat - min-lat) * world-height / (max-lat - min-lat)
  report list x y
end


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;






to initialize-bounds
  set min-lat 48.87000
  set max-lat 48.88000
  set min-lon 2.770000
  set max-lon 2.79000
end


to setup
  clear-all
  clear-drawing
  reset-ticks
  initialize-bounds

  set coordinates-data csv:from-file "parc-disneyland.csv"

  set coordinates-data but-first coordinates-data

  show word "Nombre de lignes dans le fichier : " length coordinates-data

  draw-map
end



to draw-map
  foreach coordinates-data [
    row ->
      let geometry item 0 row
      let coord_string item 1 row

      ; Extraire les coordonnées de la chaîne et les convertir en paires de latitude/longitude
      let coords parse-coordinates coord_string

      if geometry = "Polygon" [
        draw-polygon coords
      ]

      if geometry = "LineString" [
        draw-linestring coords
      ]
  ]
end

to draw-polygon [coords]
  let first-point nobody
  let previous-point nobody

  foreach coords [
    point ->
    let lat first point
    let lon last point
    let converted-point convert-latlon-to-netlogo lat lon

    if first-point = nobody [
      set first-point converted-point
    ]

    if previous-point != nobody [
      ; Relier chaque point au précédent
      ask patch item 0 previous-point item 1 previous-point [
        set pcolor green
      ]
      ask patch item 0 converted-point item 1 converted-point [
        set pcolor green
      ]
    ]
    set previous-point converted-point
  ]

  ; Relier le dernier point au premier pour fermer le polygone
  if first-point != nobody and previous-point != nobody [
    ask patch item 0 first-point item 1 first-point [
      set pcolor green
    ]
  ]
  show "polygone construit"
end



to draw-linestring [coords]
  let previous-point nobody
  foreach coords [
    point ->
    let lat first point
    let lon last point
    let current-point convert-latlon-to-netlogo lat lon

    if previous-point != nobody [
      ; Relier chaque point au précédent pour une ligne continue
      ask patch item 0 previous-point item 1 previous-point [
        set pcolor blue
      ]
      ask patch item 0 current-point item 1 current-point [
        set pcolor blue
      ]
    ]
    set previous-point current-point
  ]
  show "chemin construit"
end


to-report parse-coordinates [coord_string]
  let coords []
  let coord-list split coord_string "/"

  let i 0
  while [i < (length coord-list - 1)] [
    let lon item i coord-list
    let lat item (i + 1) coord-list
    set coords lput (list (read-from-string lon) (read-from-string lat)) coords
    set i (i + 2)
  ]

  report coords
end

I would like to know if the modeling is feasible and if so, I would like if possible some help on this subject, in order to have something prettier (if possible in 2D)

Please provide specific details about what code issue you are having trouble with- see suggestions on asking a good question and consider making a "Minimal, Reproducible Example".
